# How to fix SSL - No available certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I want to make a server SSL socket connection using the following code:

```
int port = 12000;
ServerSocketFactory ssocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket ssocket = ssocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);

// Listen for connections
Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
```

I get a "**javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.**" when doing the accept.

I created a Keystore that contains a RSA key using:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias ClubConnectionCert -keyalg RSA -validity 7 -keystore ClubConnectionKeystore
```

and I start my Program with the following options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=ClubConnectionKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword
```

Do I miss some code to read in the Keystore, or how can I test/debug that the given keystore is actually used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I executed your code and I confirm it's working fine.

Make sure **javax.net.ssl.keyStore** points **exactly** to your keystore file.
I put my keystore file at the root of my project.
Perhaps try absolute path to your keystore.

Make sure the -D parameters are set as JVM params, not Program options (in your IDE).

Good luck, you're about to make it work.

Comment: If it points to an non-existent path, you get a `FileNotFoundException`. "Make sure the -D parameters are set as JVM params" is the most likely explanation: there's no default keystore in JSSE (so not specifying the system property at all leads to this error).

Comment: Aha! I put the argument in the program arguments and not in the JVM box. Changing that makes everything work! Thank you! (And indeed I already put an absolute path in there before).